# JSONPath where key or value starts with @ character?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am attempting get a value based on the key containing @ symbol fails using JSONPath.
Cause: Since @ is the current object/element, json does not return the value.

Sample 1:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works: `$.phoneNumbers[1].type`
This works: `$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=="iPhone")].type`

Sample2:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "@type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "@type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works: `$.phoneNumbers[1].type`
**This does not work:** `$.phoneNumbers[?(@.@type=="iPhone")].type`

Any advice for dealing with keys and values containing `@` characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which jsonpath implementation you are using.
If you are using [JsonPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) then you can try something like:

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@['@type'] == "iPhone")]
```

You can evaluate jsonpath online [here](https://jsonpath.com/) which is based on `JsonPath-Plus`.